# templateResult showing selected true for multiple items

Tags: jquery-select2, jquery-select2-4

I am using jquery-select2 (4.0.0). The issue is when I select an option, then select another option, **item.selected** remains true for both options - FOREVER.  Is there some initial config option I am missing or is this a bug?

```js
function formatResult(item) {
  console.log("item selected = ", item.selected);
  return item.text;
}

$('select').select2({
  templateResult: formatResult,
  minimumResultsForSearch: Infinity,
  placeholder: "Please choose",
  multiple: false,
  maximumSelectionSize: 1
});
```

```html
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.0/css/select2.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.0/js/select2.js"></script>

<select>
  <option></option>
  <option>conan</option>
  <option>kimmel</option>
  <option>stewart</option>
  <option>colbert</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

I should start this off by saying that `item.selected` (the `selected` property of the data object) is not documented, and *will* change in the future. Why do I say it *will*? Because this bug only occurs on single select elements (as explained at the very end), but you can safely ignore it for now.

Right now the `item.selected` property is only used by Select2 on `<input />` elements, and the `item.element.selected` property is used for `<select>` elements. This will *always* be your source of truth when using a `<select>` element, as `item.element` is a reference to the `<option>` element that your browser uses for determining what data should be sent to the server.

You can see after looking at `item.element.selected` that it is correctly updated when the selection changes.

```js
function formatResult(item) {
  console.log("item selected = ", item.selected);
  console.log("item.element.selected = ", item.element && item.element.selected);
  return item.text;
}

$('select').select2({
  templateResult: formatResult,
  minimumResultsForSearch: Infinity,
  placeholder: "Please choose",
  multiple: false,
  maximumSelectionSize: 1
});
```

```html
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.0/css/select2.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.0/js/select2.js"></script>

<select>
  <option></option>
  <option>conan</option>
  <option>kimmel</option>
  <option>stewart</option>
  <option>colbert</option>
</select>
```

And yes, the `item.selected` property will be fixed in the future so it is accurate. Right now it is not updated because in a single select, new options are selected and those implicitly unselect the old options. This is unlike a multiple select, where options are explicitly selected and unselected.